# Django ModelForm not handling files correctly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I have a very basic model with an ImageField on it, and a ModelForm for uploading that image.  My form is failing, saying that my image is not valid, but if I instantiate the model's image directly from the request.FILES it works perfectly.  The file is uploaded and exists in my media directory.  See code below

Also, this is failing in the Admin center as well.

Things I'm pretty sure it is not:

- multipart/form-data
- incorrect media path settings
- permissions settings in those directories.

models.py

```
class ImageTile(BaseTile):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='tiles/')
```

forms.py

```
class ImageTileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageTile
        fields = ('image', )
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Then we do image tiles
    #if request.FILES:
    image_form = ImageTileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if image_form.is_valid():
        image_form.save()
```

template

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ image_form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ image_form.image.errors }}
    {{ image_form.image.label_tag }}
    {{ image_form.image }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

image_form.errors

```
django.forms.util.ErrorDict({'image': django.forms.util.ErrorList([u'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.'  ])})
```

terminal output from doing it manually

```
>>> from scrapbook.models import ImageTile
>>> x = ImageTile(image=request.FILES['image'])
>>> x.save()
>>> x.id
2
>>> x.image
<ImageFieldFile: tiles/cathy_orange.jpg>
>>>
```

Comment: Is PIL installed in a way that your web server can access it?  You might want to log what happens when you `from PIL import Image` in your interactive Python session and your web server test environment.  You might also want to include any differences in `sys.path` between your Django server test and your interactive environment.

Comment: Yes, PIL works and is installed just fine.  Note that I can instantiate an ImageTile object manually, using the request.FILES dictionary.  I do believe that the ImageField depends on PIL and since the image field can be populated without errors, I would take that to mean it is working as intended.

Comment: @Aaron, By "manually" I hope you mean via the python debugger at that exact point in your view function / or code literally put into that block. Otherwise, you'd definitely want to triple/quadruple check that your view environment is exactly the same as your terminal environment. By the way, I had this message on OSX after an update until I rebuilt PIL.

Comment: Yes, by manually, I do mean strait from the view block.  I'm using django-extensions runserver_plus which allows you to jump into a console in an exception.  Also solved my problem.  Putting it in as an actual answer below.

Comment: @Aaron, ah what do you know it was the same problem. Congrats!

Answer (score 3):

Problem was having a PIL install that didn't have jpeg support.  Installed libjpeg and re-installed PIL and everything worked great.

Interesting that Django ModelForms validate this but the model does not.  The model never threw an error until I tried to access the width/height attributes.